# Granting UPDATE on system table

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am making software that allows user to make CRUD operations on data stored in PostgreSQL database on RDS. I have access only to views, I can't work on tables - it's a technical assumption.

The software I have created needs to take information from database about whether the column is nullable in specified view.

I am getting information about nullability of the fields using data from *attnotnull* column in **pg_attribute** table.

By default all 'attnotnull' column values are set to false. Because of it my software does not indicate fields are required.

My idea is to change this data by hand but as I mentioned above I am using RDS and I cannot log in as superuser. I tried to grant UPDATE privilege on **pg_attribute** table to my user but I am getting "permission denied" error.

Is there any way to grant UPDATE on system table on RDS?

Comment: How are you granting update which query are you using?

Comment: Manually changing system tables is a really bad idea.

Comment: @SachinYadav I am using the following query: `GRANT UPDATE ON pg_attribute TO user;
`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I know its bad idea but I can't see any other solution.

Answer (score -1):

Please don't mess with the catalogs..

A view in PostgreSQL is little more than a table with an `ON SELECT DO INSTEAD` rule.
So as a workaround, you could first create a table and then turn it into a view:

```
CREATE TABLE to_view (
   c1 integer NOT NULL,
   c2 text,
   c3 inet NOT NULL
);

CREATE RULE "_RETURN" AS ON SELECT TO to_view DO INSTEAD
SELECT 42 AS c1,
       'string' AS c2,
       INET '127.0.0.1' AS c3;

SELECT attname,
       attnotnull
FROM pg_attribute
WHERE attrelid = 'to_view'::regclass
  AND attnum > 0
ORDER BY attnum;

 attname | attnotnull 
---------+------------
 c1      | t
 c2      | f
 c3      | t
(3 rows)
```